# Есть ли элемент списка в классе

Tags: python, массивы, list

Есть класс:

class Values:

ex1 = 255

ex2  = 109

ex3  = 0

ex4 = 77

ex5 = 60

ex6 = 72

ex7 = 33

ex8 = 229

ex9 = 233

ex10 = 108

ex11 = 24

ex12 = 59

Есть список, например:
a = [3, 5, 1, 9, 6]
и также список b = []

Нужно проверить есть ли значение из списка в классе, и если есть то перенести его во второй список.

```
for i in a:
 if (здесь то самое условие):
  b.append(i)
  print(b)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
class Values:
  ex1 = 255
  ex2 = 109
  ex3 = 0
  ex4 = 77
  ex5 = 60
  ex6 = 72
  ex7 = 33
  ex8 = 229
  ex9 = 233
  ex10 = 108
  ex11 = 24
  ex12 = 59
  ex13 = 5
  ex14 = 1

class_values = {value for (key, value) in vars(Values).items() if key.startswith('ex')}

a = [3, 5, 1, 9, 6]
b = [item for item in a if item in class_values]

print(b)
```

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ, работает как и требовалось, только я ничего не понял :) Если не затруднит, очень хотел бы увидеть какое нибудь краткое пояснение. Заранее большое спасибо!

Comment: @SuddenDumb `vars()` возвращает переменные класса словарём, `items()` - лист пар (ключ;значение) этого словаря. Мы идём по всем таким парам и проверяем что название переменной=ключ начинается с букв "ex". Если это так, то добавляем в множество `class_values` значение этой переменной. Далее конструируем лист `b` с помощью тех значений из листа `a` которые присутствуют в множестве `class_values`

Comment: @Sherlock это не генератор, а множество `set`

Comment: Извиняюсь, а есть ли возможность, не изменять список b, а каждый раз добавлять (append) к нему значения при изменении списка a ?

Comment: Дело в том что список a изменяется со временем, и нужно чтобы список b, как бы запоминал значения, которые удовлетворяют условию. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: @SuddenDumb в тот момент когда изменяете значение `a`, делайте `b.append()`. В чём проблема?

Comment: @SuddenDumb так как у вас в коде в вопросе написано, только вместо "(здесь то самое условие)" `i in class_values`

Comment: Вот результат реального кода:  print(a) print(b) (Сверху a, снизу b)    [255, 0, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40]
[255, 0]
[40, 40, 24, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40]
[24]    Здесь видно, что в первом случае в a есть числа 255 и 0, и они уходят в b, как и нужно, но затем, a изменяется, и из подходящих чисел есть 24, и оно уходит в b, а требуется результат : 255 , 0 , 24.

Comment: @SuddenDumb задайте новый вопрос с кодом, который вы используете, и ожидаемым/реальным выводом. Так не понятно, в чём проблема

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1142349/%d0%9f%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b0-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%b2-%d0%b4%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%b9-%d1%81-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b9