# Передача значений из одного списка в другой с проверкой

Tags: python, python-3.x, массивы

```
from PIL import ImageGrab , ImageOps
import pyautogui
import os
import time
import win32api
import numpy as np
class Values:
ex1 = 255
ex2 = 109
ex3 = 0
ex4 = 77
ex5 = 60
ex6 = 72
ex7 = 33
ex8 = 229
ex9 = 233
ex10 = 108
ex11 = 24
ex12 = 59

.......

def getGrid():
 state_left = win32api.GetKeyState(0x01)  
 state_right = win32api.GetKeyState(0x02)  
 while True:
   a = win32api.GetKeyState(0x01)
   b = win32api.GetKeyState(0x02)

if a != state_left:  
   state_left = a
   if a == 1 or a == 0 :
    time.sleep(0.3)
    image = ImageGrab.grab()
    for cord in Cords.cordArray:
     r, g, b = image.getpixel(cord)
     currentGrid.append(b)

    matrix = np.array(currentGrid).reshape(6, 4)
    matrix_as_list = matrix.tolist()
    class_values = {value for (key, value) in vars(Values).items() if key.startswith('ex')}
    b1 = [item for item in currentGrid if item in class_values]
    
    currentGrid.clear()
   
    
getGrid()
```

Код ищет различные цвета на экране и записывает идентификаторы в  currentGrid, после каждого щелчка мышкой этот currentGrid меняется. Нужно что-бы значения из currentGrid записывались в другой список saveGrid, причем только те, что есть в классе Values.
Пример :

```
      currentGrid = [ 108 , 77, 900] saveGrid = [108 , 77]
      currentGrid = [ 900 , 233 , 900] saveGrid = [108 , 77 , 233]
      currentGrid = [ 900 , 900 , 33] saveGrid = [108,77 ,233,33]
```

Comment: `class_values` перенесите выше, а после `currentGrid.append(b)` добавьте `if b in class_values: saveGrid.append(b)`, если я правильно понял

Comment: Почти как нужно, только оно накладывается друг на друга и повторяется [0]
[0, 0, 229]
[0, 0, 229, 109]
[0, 0, 229, 109, 109, 233]
[0, 0, 229, 109, 109, 233, 59]

Comment: Если хотите без повторений, то сделайте `saveGrid` не листом, а множеством `set` и добавляйте через `saveGrid.add(b)`

Comment: Не повторяется, но я не понимаю почему значения перемешиваются местами {60}
{0, 60}
{0, 108, 60}

Comment: `set` не сохраняет порядок элементов при добавлении, если нужен ещё и порядок, то используйте `dict`

Comment: saveGrid.update(b) не работает.  'int' object is not iterable

Comment: попробуйте `OrderedSet` отсюда https://stackoverflow.com/a/1653978

Comment: Эх, безуспешно :(

Comment: Выяснил что, множества здесь не подходят, так как они не допускают дубликатов.